# Cycles in custom JPA repository

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I recently update my Spring Boot from 2.3.4 to 2.7.11 and my tests (but not the application) seem to have stopped working.  The error I got was

> The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle

The custom JPA code I had looks like this

```java
@Repository
public class PublicationsImpl {

    @Autowired
    private Publications publications;

    public Foo someCustomOperation(String id, LocalDate xyz) {
      var myStuff = publications.findById(id).orElseThrow();
      // ... some complicated operations
      var moreStuff = publications.findBySomeComplexQuery(myStuff, xyz);
      // ...
      return ...;
    }
}
```

`Publications` has complex JPQL queries as well.

The way I fixed it was to add

```
@Autowired
@Lazy // added this line
private Publications publications;
```

But I am not sure if that's the proper answer.

Comment: The proper answer would be to remove the cycles. Can you post more infos about the affected classes and their dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

By default all Autowired dependencies are eagerly created and configured at startup. When the @Lazy annotation is present together with the @Component annotation on class level, then the component will not be eagerly created by the container, but when the component is first requested. Together with the @Autowired injection point, you need to mark it with @Lazy annotation.

So in your case
The **PublicationsImpl** bean will be created eagerly. But the Autowired **Publications** bean is annotated with the @Lazy annotation, which tells the spring container to initialize the bean only when it’s first requested.